# Rails autocomplete works in parent but not nested form. Why?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, nested-forms

in a Rails 3.2 app with JEE, I am trying to implement an autocomplete field a la Railscast #102, within a complex nested form using Cacoon.

I have managed to get similar autocomplete field working perfectly on the parent form. However I can not get the autocomplete to work on the nested form. It appears that the javascript is not being triggered.

My form looks something like

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"parent-name", :data => {:autocomplete_source => Model.order(:name).map(&:name) } %>
  <%= f.fields_for :children  do |child| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :grand_children do |grand_child| %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>"grand-child-name", :data => {:autocomplete_source => Model.order(:name).map(&:name) } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have two javascript functions

```
$(function() {
    $('.parent-name').autocomplete({
        source: $('.parent-name').data('autocomplete-source')
    });
});

$(function() {
    $('.grand-child-name').autocomplete({
        source: $('.grand-child-name').data('autocomplete-source')
    });
});
```

The parent autocomplete is working perfectly, the grandchild is not. Am I missing something? Is there a reason that this would not work in a nested form? Or have I made a mistake in my approach?

Grateful for any pointers.

**EDIT**

The grand-child elements is being added asynchronously, the parent element is being rendered on page load. This appears to be the key to the issue. When I open an existing record to edit (i.e. fields are rendered and populated on page load) the autocomplete is functioning on these fields.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Chris Drappier who pointed me in the right direction. He said I need to add my observer when adding the new form element.

I now have two jquery functions. The original

```
$(function() {
    $('.grand-child-name').autocomplete({
        source: $('.grand-child-name').data('autocomplete-source')
    });
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("focus",".grand-child-name", function() {
        $('.grand-child-name').autocomplete({
            source: $('.grand-child-name').data('autocomplete-source')
        }); 
    });
})
```

While Chris pointed me towards the .live() function, apparently this is being depreciated, and .on(focus) provides the correct functionality.

Thanks Chris!

Comment: are you rendering the entire form when the page is loaded initially? or are you inserting these elements asynchronously. also, what if you move the text field out of the grandchild into the child. does it work for you then?

Comment: On your parent are you doing accepts_nested_attributes_for in the model? http://asciicasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: @ChrisDrappier thanks for your suggestion. I am inserting elements asynchronously, and this seems to be the problem. If I open an existing record, and hence fields are rendered during load, autocomplete works. Why is this? And what can I do about it? I really appreciate any pointers in the right direction to help me learn this.

Comment: @CaleyWoods thanks for your idea. I have nested attributes defined in the model. This doesn't appear to be the issue as autocomplete works on elements rendered during page load. See above.

Comment: @AndyHarvey I've added an answer to your question.  I would go ahead and update the text of the question to include the fact that the form elements are being added asynchronously. This is a key point to the resolution.

Comment: I suggest you place your solution as a separate answer. It makes the Q&A easier to follow. You can still attribute @ChrisDrappier by upvoting him, and linking to his answer in yours. That way, the "question" is not cluttered with extra details. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky one, but I believe the problem is that you have to add your observer when you add the new form element as well. if you are using jquery, there is functionality to handle this case.  see the api docs in jquery for [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) . I think that should get you where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks @chris, I will look into this and report back.

Comment: wow, what a cool fix! I used .on() rather than .live(), but the fix worked first time — unusual for me as my javascript skills are not that hot. I will post my ful solution above in the question. Thanks Chris!

Comment: @ChrisDrappier `live` is now deprecated.